# コマンドプロンプトでソースファイルを実行しようとするとエディタが勝手に開く。

Tags: python, python3

以下のようにソースファイルを`c:\python>test.py`とcmdで指定して実行しました。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

以前はそれでソースファイルが実行されたのですが、今はそうしても

```
[main 2020-05-27T23:31:10.951Z] update#setState idle
(node:5528) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
(node:5528) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
(node:5528) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
(node:5528) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
(node:5948) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
(node:5948) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
[main 2020-05-27T23:31:40.953Z] update#setState checking for updates
[main 2020-05-27T23:32:02.847Z] update#setState idle
```

このような文字が出てVScodeでプログラムを開くだけになってしまいました。
どうすれば以前のようにcmdでソースファイルを実行できるでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.py ファイルの関連付けを修正し、pythonに関連付けすればいいです